# Policy Gradient algorithm gets worse over time

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I tried to write a Policy Gradient algorithm for the Video game Pong.
Here's the Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import gym
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from os import getcwd

num_episodes = 1000
learning_rate = 0.01

rewards = []

env_name = 'Pong-v0'
env = gym.make(env_name)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,(None,)+env.observation_space.shape)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,(None,env.action_space.n))

def net(x):
    layer1 = tf.layers.flatten(x)
    layer2 = tf.layers.dense(layer1,200,activation=tf.nn.softmax)
    layer3 = tf.layers.dense(layer2,env.action_space.n,activation=tf.nn.softmax)

    return layer3

logits = net(x)
loss = tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(y,logits)
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()

with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
    sess.run(init)

    for episode in range(num_episodes):
        print('episode:',episode+1)

        total_reward = 0
        losses = []
        training_data = []
        observation = env.reset()
        while True:
            if max(0.1, (episode+1)/num_episodes) > np.random.uniform():
                probs = sess.run(logits,feed_dict={x:[observation]})[0]
                action = np.argmax(probs)
            else:
                action = env.action_space.sample()

            onehot = np.zeros(env.action_space.n)
            onehot[action] = 1
            training_data.append([observation,onehot])
            observation, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
            total_reward += reward

            if done:
                break

        if total_reward >= 0:
            learning_rate = 0.01
        else:
            learning_rate = -0.01

        for sample in training_data:
            l,_ = sess.run([loss,train],feed_dict={x:[sample[0]], y:[sample[1]]})
            losses.append(l)
            print('loss:',l)
        print('average loss:',sum(losses)/len(losses))

        saver.save(sess,getcwd()+'/model.ckpt')

        rewards.append(total_reward)
        plt.plot(range(episode+1),rewards)
        plt.ylabel('total reward')
        plt.xlabel('episodes')
        plt.savefig(getcwd()+'/reward_plot.png')
```

But after I trained my Network, the plot which the script made seemed to suggest that the Network got worse towards the end. Also during the last Episode the loss was the same for all Training examples (~0.68) and when I try to test the Network, the paddle of the Player just sits there motionless. Is there any way I can improve my Code?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would ask you to familiarize yourself with how to code neural networks using tensorflow because there is where the problem lies. You provide `activation=tf.nn.softmax` in both the nn layers which should be a terminal layer (since you are trying to find the maximum action probability). You can change it to `tf.nn.relu` in the second layer. There is a bigger problem with the `learning_rate`:

```
if total_reward >= 0:
    learning_rate = 0.01
else:
    learning_rate = -0.01
```

[Negative learning rate makes absolutely no sense](https://www.quora.com/Can-a-learning-rate-in-a-neural-network-be-negative). You want the learning rate to be positive (you can use a constant 0.01 for now).

Also, another comment, you have not mentioned the `observation_space` shape but I am going to assume it is a 2D matrix. Then you can reshape it before inputting it into `x`. So you would not need to unnecessarily use `tf.flatten`.

Comment: I don't see why my learning rate shouldn't be negative. The Post you linked says that the only Problem with a negative learning rate is, that it will maximize the loss. But that's exactly what I want to do.

Comment: Why would you want to maximize your loss? The loss function is the discounted reward multiplied by the log of action probabilities. Now, if the reward is positive, the action becomes more likely while if the reward is negative it becomes less likely. If you minimize your loss when the reward is positive and maximize when it is negative, the net result would be the network not learning any of the key features which is happening in your case.

Comment: No I am pretty sure I am not.

Comment: I think you are, [deep q learning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79pmNdyxEGo&t=394s), [policy gradient](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pN7ETkOizGM)

Comment: Good. Best of luck.